# Proving the Equation of a Slope of a Parabole. Trying to understand an equation of a manual. Explanation of counter-intuitive step.

Tags: conic-sections, parabolic-pde

By trying to prove the equation of the tangent of a parabola i cannot understand a step in the equations.

Tangent of a parabola is calculated with the equation $$yy1 = p(x+x1)$$ and the equation of the parabola is $$y^2 = 2px$$

[image: Tangent of Parabola]

Assume as in the picture above a tangent that crosses the Parabola in tow points $$ M1(x1,y1)$$ $$M2(x2,y2)$$

The slope will be $$ λ = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)$$

So we will have a line with the equation: $$ y - y1 = [(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)]*(x-x1)$$
Since M1 and M2 belong to the Parabole we have $$y1^2 = 2px1$$ and   $$y2^2 = 2px2$$

**Afterwards (and this is the step i cannot understand) he just writes that we have:**

$$ y2^2 - y1^2 = 2p(x2-x1)  $$

Why? How does he decide to simply subtract the squares? Is there a logical step before that makes this step plausible? He just does it because he knows he can? I just cannot fathom it.

Afterwards until the prove the next steps which i understand are:

$$(y2-y1)(y2+y1) = 2p(x2-x1)$$ $$(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (2p)/(y2+y1)$$

So the line of the equation takes the form: $$y-y1 = [(2p)/(y2 + y1)]*(x-x1)$$

or $$(y-y1)(y2+y1) = 2p (x - x1)$$

If M2 it going almost on M1 the coordinates of two are identical so we write:

$$(y-y1)(y1+y1) = 2p (x - x1)$$

$$y1(y-y1) = p (x - x1)$$

$$yy1 = p(x+x1)$$

For the love of me i cannot understand why he subtracts the squares? How does he make the logical step?

Comment: But do you agree that for any two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ on parabola, $y2^2 - y1^2 = 2p(x2-x1)$?

Comment: They belong to the Parabola so they are $$y^2 = 2px$$ and that applies for the two points. Why does he decide to substract those points? What is his line of thinking? @mathlover i am on it half a day

Comment: It surely does not seem very intuitive but the idea is to simplify $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. There is a more straightforward way to get to the equation of tangent at point $(x_1, y_1)$ though.

Comment: @MathLover What is the line of thinking? Is he subtracting the squares simply because he can? It there a thread of logic behind this step?

Comment: There is freedom to just do it but why. Is there something i dont see? It does seem very sudden and totaly out of the blue in my eyds

Comment: you are right on that. The step is not very intuitive but they are doing it to simplify $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ which becomes evident only in the next step.

Comment: So he is doing it to simplify the slope part that is clear to me. It is definitely Not intuitive. It got me scratching my head trying to figure out why did he did that kind of move. Seems inconsequantial @MathLover Thank you for this feedback!!! It means a lot  tome

Comment: You are welcome. Also, you can get to that final equation by just finding slope at the point of tangent and writing the line of equation directly.

Comment: You may always subtract equations. $a=b\text{ and }c=d$ imply $a-c=b-d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are deriving an equation, but, instead of a single logical sequence of steps, we have the abrupt introduction of a new idea which then "magically" leads to the final result.

This is the kind of thing that puzzled many of my students and left them wondering how they could ever be good at mathematics if this kind of "trick" was required to get a result.
I think this kind of derivation is best  taught in a classroom where we can try to imagine what the thinking behind it is. Suppose we don't know the result. We set out the basic equations as you have done, we get to $y-y1=[(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)]*(x-x1)$ And then we have nowhere to go. What do we do when we have equations with unknowns? We try to eliminate some by substituting from other equations. The only other equations we have are for the parabola. We see squares are involved and we realise that the difference of two squares gives us an expression containing $y2-y1$. So let's try that. And the rest falls out.
We then tidy this all up as a formal proof, losing the thought processes that went into it, and leaving the student pondering how can I ever acquire this kind of insight.So, to answer your question, the formal proof makes it look like a sudden leap, but the thinking might be no less intuitive than that used in the formal processes for solving simultaneous equations.

Comment: i cant thank you enough for your answer. Something like that came late at night to me after long thinking. Since we want y2 - y1 and we know that we can create this with the squares we can experiment to remove the slope part of the equation that uses y2-y1 and insert p of the parapola to construct the type that creates an equation of line based on the parabola machinery aka p.

Comment: Finally i find it a bit of unfair that this mathematics book skips even the mininum of explaining. The person becomes puzzled und frustrated since there is no connection or logic thread! Thank so much!!!! Thanks a Kazillion!